# Why matchInDirectory should return mount points

Tags: tcl

I am implementing Tcl Filesystem object. Can someone explain what are mount points. Why they are needed. And what will happen if my matchInDirectoryProc will not return any mount point like native filesystem implementation does?

Let's say there is foo/bar/vfs.myzip where vfs.myzip is a container file for which I am implementing filesystem. I am assuming that vfs.myzip is a mount point. Should my implementation return foo/bar/vfs.myzip if type is TCL_GLOB_TYPE_MOUNT, path is foo/bar/ and patter is "*". What if patter will be "*/*"?

Comment: Implementing a `Tcl_Filesystem`? Now that's deep magic!

Comment: Donal you are my last hop to get help on this. And you are saying that is a deep magic. Should I give up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mount point is a prefix of a path that is the root of a particular virtual filesystem (the native filesystem is special-cased, IIRC). Everything in a VFS will appear below that mount point.

So, suppose `/foo/bar/vfs.myzip` is the mount point, and inside the VFS is a file `abc.txt`, a directory `def`, and another file `def/ghi.html`. In that case, once correctly mounted the following would exist:

- `/foo/bar/vfs.myzip/abc.txt`
- `/foo/bar/vfs.myzip/def`
- `/foo/bar/vfs.myzip/def/ghi.html`

Now, the `matchInDirectoryProc` is used inside the globbing code. It's purpose is to return the list of directory entries that match a particular set of constraints in a particular (virtual) directory. It's wrapped inside the Tcl API function [`Tcl_FSMatchInDirectory`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/FileSystem.htm), whose documentation notes that:

> Note that the **glob** code implements recursive patterns internally, so this function will only ever be passed simple patterns, which can be matched using the logic of **string match**. To handle recursion, Tcl will call this function frequently asking only for directories to be returned. A special case of being called with a `NULL` pattern indicates that the path needs to be checked only for the correct type.

That is, don't worry about that `*/*` pattern; you'll never see it.

I'm not *entirely* sure how the search for mounts works, but I think it is determining if there is a mount handled by the particular VFS that matches a path. The main example of doing this that I can find online is the TclVFS package, which is rather odd in a few ways. [Here's the relevant code](http://tclvfs.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tclvfs/tclvfs/generic/vfs.c?revision=1.65&view=markup) but I think that it isn't easy to understand. But for all that, one thing *is* relatively clear: it's asking about mounts within a particular directory, and not recursively.

Thus, if your mount point is `/foo/bar/vfs.myzip` then when your code is called asking about mount points in `/foo/bar` it ought to return an entry for `vfs.myzip`. If that's the only mount point you maintain, that's the only thing you need to handle in that case.

Assuming that I'm correct anyway. I don't know the virtual filesystem layer well, so this is based on reading code and documentation, not real experience…

Comment: And now you can see why it took me a while to reply. I was researching the answer. :–)

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is really helpful.